# Change column order in deedle frame

Tags: c#, dataframe, deedle

What is the best way to change column order in deedle frame? For example if I have a deedle frame `df` with columns `height`, `Name`, and `phone`, but I need it in order `Name`, `phone`, and `height`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deedle has [`RealignRows` extension method](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/blob/master/src/Deedle/FrameExtensions.fs#L758-758), but it turns out that we don't have `RealignColumns`. This is an omission and if you send a PR to Deedle adding this, that would be awesome!

It can be implemented by looking at the series of columns, realigning the columns and turning that back into a data frame. In C#, this looks as follows:

```
Frame.FromColumns(df.Columns.Realign(new[] { "key 1", "key 2" }));
```